# Flutter runs the basic demo application everytime

Tags: dart, flutter, hot-reload

Flutter runs the basic demo application every time I run the app. My code changes are reflected only after performing a hot restart. I tried running `flutter clean` but no help. This is really frustrating. What could be the reason?

Comment: what you are passing in your runApp() method?

Comment: `void main() => runApp(new MyApp());` `MyApp()` is a StatelessWidget.
Here is the entire `main.dart`: https://pastebin.com/VQqTdhEr

Comment: You have used MateriaApp inside MaterialApp I guess that can be a problem.